# Keeping count to Occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to do a specialized count. This is patient medical data.

```
Patient_ID    Appointment        DoctorID   ApptType   Completed

10000         20160531090000      001        ABA           Y
10000         20150530100000      001        ABA           Y 
10005         20160202140000      001        LDA           Y
10005         20160531110000      002        CCN           Y
10005         20160303151515      002        CCN           Y
10015         20150301120000      001        TRI           Y
```

The results here should be, want want to export this information So the Doctor has a dataset of his patients, based on highest count a patient had completed appt.

```
DoctorID   PatientID
001         10000
001         10015
002         10005
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Your description and desired results do not match.  What do you mean by "highest count"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the most common doctor for each patient.  You can do this with `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select dp.*
from (select doctorid, patientid, count(*) as cnt
             row_number() over (partition by patientid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by doctorid, patientid
     ) dp
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are ties, this returns an arbitrary doctor.  If you want all of them, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
select DoctorID,count(Patient_ID) Appt_Completed,Patient_ID into #t1 from test
where completed='Y'
group by DoctorID,Patient_ID
having count(Patient_ID) > 1

select * from (
select DoctorID,Patient_ID from #t1
UNION
select DoctorID,Patient_ID from test where Patient_ID NOT IN ( select distinct Patient_ID from #t1)
) A

drop table #t1
```

Output :-

```
DoctorID    Patient_ID
   001       10000
   001       10015
   002       10005
```